# Why can't I install Woocommerce theme on WordPress in Local?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Everyone!

I am learning WordPress now. While developing a new site with WordPress in my local environment.

I was trying to install Woocommerce theme. I had some bug like this.

```
The package could not be installed. 
The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.
Theme installation failed.
```

There are some solutions on Google. But they are all not suitable for my error case.

Here is the solution of my problem.

The error caused because I was trying to install Woocommerce plugin that downloaded from internet as Woocommerce theme.

There are Woocommerce plugin and Woocommerce theme and their name is same ( like woocommerce.6.7.0.zip).

It's just looks like a funny mistake but it maybe cause for some beginners.

So I have posted this message. I wish this post become help for wordpress beginners.

Comment: Hi Jacob. While posting a question you can check the box "Answer your own question" and then enter the solution there. The way you posted it now you have put everything in the question, and nothing in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the solution of my problem.**

The error caused because I was trying to install Woocommerce plugin that downloaded from internet as Woocommerce theme.

There are Woocommerce plugin and Woocommerce theme and their name is same ( like woocommerce.6.7.0.zip).

It's just looks like a funny mistake but it maybe cause for some beginners.

So I have posted this message. I wish this post become help for wordpress beginners.